# QWidget inherit from custom QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget

In Qt C++, is it possible to create a custom `QWidget` and then reuse this custom `QWidget` for all `QWidget` (that inherit all from the custom `QWidget`) of the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I have misunderstood the question, but you can just create your custom `QWidget`, then use it everywhere.

```
class derivedQWidget : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

  derivedQWidget();
  virtual ~derivedQWidget();
}

class myWidget : public derivedQWidget 
{
  ...
}

class myWidget2 : public derivedQWidget 
{
  ...
}
```

If the question is: Can we reimplement `QWidget`?, no you can't.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved in this mode:

the first class, **Widget.h**:

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~Widget();

    QPushButton *getBtn() const;
    void setBtn(QPushButton *value);

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *evt);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *evt);

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QPushButton *btn;
    QPoint oldPos;
};
```

and the second class **widExt.h**, that inherit from Widget:

```
#ifndef WIDEXT_H
#define WIDEXT_H

#include "widget.h"

namespace Ui {
    class widExt;
}

class widExt : public Widget
{
public:
    widExt();


private slots:
    void on_dial_2_actionTriggered(int action);

private:
    Ui::widExt *ui;
};

#endif // WIDEXT_H
```

with the relative **widExt.cpp**:

```
#include "widext.h"
#include "ui_widext.h"

widExt::widExt() : ui(new Ui::widExt)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void widExt::on_dial_2_actionTriggered(int action)
{

}
```

in this mode, i inherit all from the first class and i can customize other classes independently.